# Cannot resolve symbol 'R' in android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I know this may sound like a duplicate, but I have read and tried avery answer posted here. It is just not working for me.

What do I need to do to fix this?

only `android.R` is working ,  I can't use R directly. I have been hunting the solution for few days. I didn't really wanted to go back to eclipse but I wasted a lot of time already trying to resolve this.

any idea?

Things I tried:

- [clean gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18183656/3205189)
- [Sync gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20068221/3205189)
- [Checked for xml errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17111686/3205189)
- [Answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23066011/3205189)

and more....

Comment: could you explain in detail what and which answers you tried ?

Comment: @DuKes0mE I added my attemps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to do:
Be sure you delete any stray imports lines that are pulling in android.R or any other package.R, then re-ruild/clean restart eclipse/android studio.

Comment: please elaborate more on which file do I need to check, I have no idea where to find these

Comment: All of your Activity files (Any thing that extends Activity). The import statements will be at the top of the files.

Comment: I tried that, error remains. I know this was the way to fix it in eclipse

Comment: `Android Studio` as indicated in my title

Comment: Sorry, have you tried deleting all of the build files (in the build/ dir) And then rebuilding? Also be sure to check that you have no syntax errors in your xml files and Android Manifest.

Comment: Glad I could help! Sorry it took a million comments

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I tried importing an existing Eclipse Android Project into `Android Studio`. The issue was resolved when I removed the following code in the build.gragle file :

here is the code

```
`dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4+

}`
```