# "Cannot resolve symbol R" but app builds with no errors

Tags: java, android

I am having the same problem as some others have had on **SO**. In my project android studio says that it cannot resolve symbol R.

The weird thing is that it builds fine. My problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421104/android-studio-marks-r-in-red-with-error-message-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-but?page=2&tab=oldest#tab-top) post on **SO**.

The only thing that was mentioned in his answer is that this problem can occur when collaborating with others and i have had to download a master copy of project from GitHub because of errors.

I have tried the following with my project:

Cleaning project
Rebuilding project.
Renaming all files with spelling mistakes (helloworld to hello_world)
Changing the project name from MyApp-Master to the original name MyApp.
Running android lint to find any errors in the syntax of the code and fixing them
Using values instead of hard coded attributes

I have also combed through the **SO** posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111480/android-studio-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbol-r) but the suggestions where not helpful unfortunately.

I am using android studio 3.2.1

I have not included all classes where R is not resolved because it is in all of them. 
But here is the **MainActivity.class**

```
   package com.example.cohen.theepiccalculator;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


     private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
     private int drawerId;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_button_drop_down);
        }


        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);


        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                drawerId = menuItem.getItemId();
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                selectItem(drawerId);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                return true;
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position){


        switch (position){
            case R.id.nav_currency :
                Intent intentC = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InputActivityCurrency.class);
                startActivity(intentC);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Currency", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_length :
                Intent intentL = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InputActivityLength.class);
                startActivity(intentL);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Length", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_weight :
                Intent intentW = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InputActivityWeight.class);
                startActivity(intentW);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Weight", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_temp :
                Intent intentT = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InputActivityTemperature.class);
                startActivity(intentT);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Temp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_area :
                Intent intentA = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InputActivityArea.class);
                startActivity(intentA);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Area", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_speed :
                Intent intentS = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InputActivitySpeed.class);
                startActivity(intentS);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Speed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_vol :
                Intent intentV = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InputActivityVolume.class);
                startActivity(intentV);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Vol", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

        }


    }
}
```

And here is the related **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bluetwo"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include

            android:id="@+id/tbar"
            layout="@layout/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/equels"
            android:layout_width="101dp"
            android:layout_height="183dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/point"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_button_equals_orange" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eight"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/seven"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/seven"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/seven"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_button_eight_blue"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nine"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/eight"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/eight"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/eight"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_button_nine_blue"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/times"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/persent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/persent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/persent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_button_times_blue"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/devide"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/times"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/times"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/times"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_button_devide_blue"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ValueTextBox"
            android:layout_width="422dp"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/back"
            android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
            android:background="@color/bluesemi"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center|end"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            app:fontFamily="@font/zonaprothin"
            android:textColor="@color/bluetwo"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/seven"
            android:layout_marginBottom="92dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_button_back_space_blue"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/persent"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/back"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/back"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/back"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_button_persentage_blue"
             />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/four"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/one"
            android:layout_marginBottom="92dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_button_four_blue" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/five"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/four"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/four"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/four"
            android:layout_marginStart="103.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="103.5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_button_five_blue" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/six"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/five"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="207dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="207dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_button_six_blue"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/zero"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-92dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_button_one_blue" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/one"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/one"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/one"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_button_two_blue" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/two"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/two"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/two"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_button_three_blue"
             />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plus"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/equels"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/six"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/six"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/six"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_button_plus_blue" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/minus"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/nine"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nine"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/nine"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_button_minus_blue" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/seven"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/four"
            android:layout_marginBottom="92dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_button_seven_blue" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/point"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/zero"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/zero"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/zero"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/zero" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/zero"
            android:layout_width="205dp"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_button_zero_blue" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/draw_items" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

If there is anything i have left out that might be helpful please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

when R fails, usually the error is in the xml or possibly not find a resource such as menu, images etc.
You can do a build> rebuild project and attach the error.

good luck

Comment: Hi @Roman Gajardo, sorry for my ignorance but how would i attach the error?

Comment: you should look below: says LogCat should show an error, or if you press ctrl + 6. then copy the error

Comment: Hi @RomanGajardo, I'm not sure if there was meant to be a link in your comment or not